# is there a network setup wizard for ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ethernet

I have a window 7 computer and this one used to be XP.  They were networked (ethernet).  I installed Ubuntu  18.04 as dual boot so I can get accustimed before I remove the XP.  But neither the Win7 sees the Ubuntu nor the Ubuntu sees the Win7.  Is there any kind of setup wizard that can look for and setup the connection? 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "sees"? Do both machines have an IP address? If you have a DHCP server (a home router for example) they probably get a dynamic IP. Can you ping the IP of one machine from the other and vice versa?

Comment: Eh. How is the actual setup. Because if (Nautilus/Nemo/etc) option Places -> Network shows nothing you should not have a network. That should always show systems that are connected in your network. Assuming DHCP that is. That makes this easy and automatic :)

Comment: See, I guess I don't even know enough to answer your questions.  On windows, I just click the network setup wizard and it's done.  That's why I was asking about a setup wizard for ubuntu..  As for "seeing", if I click "files" and then "network" the win7 does not show, nothing is there.  Same for win7, if I look at the network, all it shows is itself and no other computers.  When I had this computer as XP, and clicked on the network on either one, the other computer was also listed.  I have no idea how to make that happen on Ubuntu.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu and it connected itself to the internet.  I didn't have to know or do a thing.  Isn't there something like that for network setup or detection?  Or do you have to know all about networks and how they work if you want to use Ubuntu on a network?

Comment: Like I said: open your file browser and pick network on the left panel. that should list all machines connected to your network.

Comment: I thought I said that. I did open the file icon and then the "other" and clicked "network" and it says the folder is empty.  So it's not listing anything.  I think it's great that it recognizes all my XP drives and I can access all the files on them but nothing for networks..